# Set a string of HTML equal to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I declare a string of HTML and set it equal to a variable. I can't think of any reason it would generate an error, yet here it is:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on Ln 136.

```
Ln 136: new_comment = '
    <li class="photobooth-comment">
       <span class="username">
          <a href="#">You</a>
       </span>
       <span class="comment-text">
          ' + text + '
       </span>
       <span class="comment-time">
          2d
       </span>
    </li>
';
```

Comment: Javascript does not like linefeeds in strings. Change them to \n or escape them with \ if you need them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808042/which-browsers-support-multi-line-strings/13808106#13808106

Comment: Got "text" variable defined?

Comment: Alexander was first to answer (actually second after my comment but still deserves the tick for good answer).

Comment: @mplungjan True; I saw Alexander had answered before me after I clicked submit for my answer. However, (without wanting to sound petty) my answer was more thorough and gave a variety of solutions.

Comment: Only with the one liner. The concatenation was mentioned. Not important...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include line breaks in your actual code to make it easier to read, you're going to need to escape each one with a backslash, e.g.:

```
var new_comment = '\
    <li class="photobooth-comment">\
       <span class="username">\
          <a href="#">You</a>\
       </span>\
       <span class="comment-text">\
          ' + text + '\
       </span>\
       <span class="comment-time">\
          2d\
       </span>\
    </li>\
';
```

Or you're going to need to concatenate them as individual strings, like so:

```
var new_comment = ''+
    '<li class="photobooth-comment">' +
       '<span class="username">' +
          '<a href="#">You</a>' +
       '</span>' +
       '<span class="comment-text">' +
          text +
       '</span>' +
       '<span class="comment-time">' +
          '2d' +
       '</span>' +
    '</li>'+
'';
```

Or simply put it all on one line:

```
var new_comment = '<li class="photobooth-comment"><span class="username"><a href="#">You</a></span><span class="comment-text">' + text + '</span><span class="comment-time">2d</span></li>';
```

Not so easy to read but neater for your JavaScript!

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can do to what you want is escaping the newline.

```
new_comment = '\
    <li class="photobooth-comment">\
       <span class="username">\
          <a href="#">You</a>\
       </span>\
       <span class="comment-text">\
          ' + text + '\
       </span>\
       <span class="comment-time">\
          2d\
       </span>\
    </li>\
';
```

Aside from this, you can also use string concatenation.

(I found a possible duplicate: [How to create multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/805107/417685))

Answer (score 0):

You are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), So, with jquery you can put the `<li>` in your HTML page and use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method that gets the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element like this

```
 var new_comment = $(".photobooth-comment").html();
   //do what you want to
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you. But, you are not considering the `text` variable. So, this is prone to fail

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naughty PHP inspired method.
I post it here as a mental exercise. Please do not downvote...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pMSc8/)

```
var new_comment; /*<<<EOF 
    <li class="photobooth-comment">
       <span class="username">
          <a href="#">You</a>
       </span>
       <span class="comment-text">
          $text
       </span>
       <span class="comment-time">
          2d
       </span>
    </li>
EOF*/
// note the script tag here is the hardcoded as the first tag 
new_comment=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML.split("EOF")[1]; 
alert(new_comment.replace('$text','Here goes some text'));
```

Comment: "*... I leave the replacement of the text var as an exercise for the reader...*," are you kidding me? If that's the case this is not the correct place for this

Comment: That's a naïve way. But, ok, nice try :)

Comment: I know it works. But, you just added another layer of complexity. For instance, `$text` as a string and `$text` as a variable can't be differentiated