# jQuery shorten code

Tags: jquery

I want to shorten this code, so I want to make 3 or 4 lines,

but if I try to make 3 lines, than it works not.

```
$('#uebersicht').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow"><li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child ui-last-child ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-has-alt"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit"><img class="ui-li-thumb" src='+icerik.Resim+'><h2 class="ui-li-heading">'+moschee+'</h2><p class="ui-li-desc">'+results[0].formatted_address+'</p><p class="ui-li-desc">'+hesapla(meineLongitude,meineLatitude,icerik.Position.Longitude,icerik.Position.Latitude)+'</p></a></div></div><a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" title="Purchase album" class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-notext" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="#purchase"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span><span data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></span></span></a></li></ul>');
```

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Trust me, you should not insert a string of such a length via `append`.

Comment: in the middle i have tried

Comment: you should really split it up :/ firstly, it makes it easier to debug

Comment: so i can get an overview

Comment: @Christoph, what is the preferred way to insert a large html fragment into the DOM? And are you speaking from a performance point of view, or just readability/maintainability?

Comment: both, 1) this is nowhere near maintainable 2) [the performance is horrible](http://jsperf.com/documentfragment-appendchild-vs-jquery-append). Use native JS with [document fragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) for such huge junks of html.

Comment: Check out [rev 19 of that jsperf](http://jsperf.com/documentfragment-appendchild-vs-jquery-append/19), notably the last case. Inserting a large html string with a single call to `append` gives pretty good performance. In [another revision of the test](http://jsperf.com/documentfragment-appendchild-vs-jquery-append/20), you can see that `append(htmlString)` does well even with only 50 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Escape your javascript newlines with `\` character, like this:

```
$('#uebersicht').append('<ul data-role="lisview" data-split-icon="gear"\
 data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview \
ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">');
```

Above it's a shortened version of your long string, but you get the idea, use `\` to break javascript new lines.

Comment: this makes me want to cry... You cannot indent the code this way and it's altogether just a horrible solution.

Comment: This method of breaking up strings [is supported by current browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808042/which-browsers-support-multi-line-strings), and will be supported going forward as it was added in the 5th edition of the ECMAScript standard. However it is considered by some to be [bad practice](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multiline_string_literals#Multiline_string_literals).

Answer (score 0):

When you need to append multiple HTML element the best way to take it ordered and clean is to split up the `.append()` in this way:

```
$('#myID').append('<p>lorem ipsum</p>')
          .append('<p>dolor sit amet...</p>')
          .append('etc...');
```

but is not very good append too many elements...

Answer (score 0):

Split it wherever you want.  Just end the string anywhere, add a plus sign, line feed, and start the string again.  e.g.

```
$('#uebersicht').append(
    '<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" ' +
        'data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true" ' +
        'class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">' +
        '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true"' +
             'data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="right"' +
             'data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ' +
             'ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child ui-last-child ' +
             'ui-btn-up-c">' +
          '<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-has-alt">' +
          '<div class="ui-btn-text">' +
          '<a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">' +
          '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src='+icerik.Resim+'>' +
          '<h2 class="ui-li-heading">'+moschee+'</h2>' +
          '<p class="ui-li-desc">' +
              results[0].formatted_address+ 
          '</p> ' +
          '<p class="uii-desc">' +   
            hesapla(meineLongitude, eineLatitude, icerik.Position.Longitude,       
               icerik.Position.Latitude) +
          '</p></a></div></div>' +
          '<a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" ' +
            'data-transition="pop" title="Purchase album" ' +
            'class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-notext"' +
            'data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" ' +
            'data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="notext" ' +
            'data-theme="c" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="#purchase"> ' +
          '<span class="ui-btn-inner">' +
          '<span class="ui-btn-text"></span>' +
          '<span data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" ' +
             'data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" ' +
             'data-theme="d" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-d ui-shadow ' +
             'ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext">' +
          '<span class="ui-btn-inner">' +
          '<span class="ui-btn-text"></span>' +
          '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;' +
          '</span></span></span></span></a></li></ul>'
);
```

I could've done this cleaner, with better indenting, but you should get the idea.  From what I understand, this is better than calling `append` on each line - each append takes a relatively large amount of time to do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest solution would be to make a jquery container, add all elements via append/appendTo and insert the whole object into the dom in the end to avoid too many dom manipulations/redrawings.

But with your html string this could result in quite a long script...

```
var $list = $('<ul>');

$list.data({
    'role': 'listview',
    'split-icon': 'gear',
    // etc...
}).addClass('ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow');

$li = $('<li>');
// take the base object and clone it if used multiple times
$li.clone().data({
    // fill up data, add classes etc.
}).addClass('classes').appendTo($list);

// and so on with each element, use all the beautiful jquery functions available
// there's no dom manipulation to this point, performance still fine
// now in the end, insert the object into the dom:
$list.appendTo('#uebersicht');
```

**Maybe better way for you:**

```
var html = '';

html += '<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">';
html += '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child ui-last-child ui-btn-up-c">';
html += '<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-has-alt">';

// etc. just make a line for each tag or split it if too long

$('#uebersicht').append(html);
```